# Set billing details when using Stripe Express Checkout Element

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, stripes, stripe-payment-intent, stripe-payments-js

NodeJS.
I have one issue with expressCheckout API.
https://stripe.com/docs/elements/express-checkout-element/migration#mpan

For the payment request button we will use "ev.paymentMethod" to get card information and use the API [Create a PaymentMethod](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create) to create and set billing information.

When using Express Checkout Element I can't get card information from (e.g. Google Pay) to create payment method and set billing data.

Do we have any other way to assign billing information without creating payment method?

I tried searching and researching but I didn't get any suitable results to solve the problem I'm having.

Comment: [Billing address](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-billing_details-address) is attached to a payment method. You should be able to set the billing details under [`payment_method_data.billing_details`](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_payment#confirm_payment_intent-options-confirmParams-payment_method_data-billing_details) in `stripe.confirmPayment()` at Step 6 of Express Checkout Element integration [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/elements/express-checkout-element/accept-a-payment#submit-the-payment)

Comment: Resolve problems. Thanks @yuting